# MongoDB requests very slow to return results

Tags: mongodb, express, redux

So, I only have a few documents in my Mongo DB. For example, I have this basic find request (see below) which takes 4 seconds to return a 1.12KB JSON, before the component re-render.

```
app.get('/mypath', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(urlDb, (err, db) => {
        let Mycoll = db.collection('Mycoll');

        Mycoll.find({}).toArray( (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            else{
                res.status(200).json(data);
            }           
        })

        db.close();
    })
});
```

Sometimes for that same component to re-render, with the same request, it takes 8 seconds (which equals an eternity for an Internet user).

Is it supposed to take this long ? I can imagine a user of my app starting to think ("well, that doesn't work") and close it right before the results show.

Is there anything you could point me to to optimize the performance ? Any tool you would recommend to analyze what exactly causes this bottleneck ? Or anything I did wrong ?

At this stage, I don't incriminate React/Redux, because with no DB requests involved, my other components render fast.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to MongoDB with a utility like Mongochef and retrieve items from the database? That would help you to check if MongoDB is the bottleneck.

Comment: you are creating new connection everytime. consider having a dbpool

Comment: I hope DB has proper indices??

Comment: Yes, I am creating a connection each time I do an express request. This may be what is slowing things down. Is there any document you can point me to about dbpool ? I'm also trying mongochef now. Thanks for the suggestion.